# Blank project cross-platform throws error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

I just started working with cross-platform. I only created the project and I see a popup saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I'm trying to run the Android app and see that I have on Android Android SDK API level 26. I can't find anything about this, as many answers where about the code or Android SDK API level 19-21 and 22. Any idea why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: is this happening at runtime, or is it an error in the IDE when you create the project?

Comment: it's at runtime. I just run the project and is telling me that I have some errors and if I want to continue. And if I press yes, I get this popup with the error.

Comment: instead of ignoring the errors it finds and selecting "continue" you should probably stop and resolve them

Comment: I stopped and nothing happend. It gave no error :)

Comment: If you just build the solution does it build cleanly with no errors?

Comment: @MaraM You should check the last time modified code ,which can result it.The most problem about this error is project used a null object.You need to find it.

Comment: @Jason if I build the solution it tells me "Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped".

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I wrote nothing in the project. I just created an empty project and wanted to run it to see if it works. The project is empty as the Visual Studio create it.

Comment: @MaraM Okey, could you share sample project with me, I will check it.Maybe the probelm is missing Configuration in VS.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT thank you so much, but please tell me how can I send you the project.

Comment: @MaraM You can upload your project here(https://www.dropbox.com/) ,and share the link with me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192208/discussion-between-mara-m-and-junior-jiang-msft).